# getting the "title" between the names

Tags: postgresql

The name I'm working on is formatted like this:

```
King, Mr. Jay Thomas
Smith, Miss. Jane
```

How do I get the middle title part only using Postgres?

I'm a noob so this is definitely wrong:

```
SELECT position('%#,"  #"%#' for '#') AS TITLE
FROM  titanic;`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SUBSTRING` with the regex pattern `\w+\.`:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(title from '\w+\.')
FROM titanic;
```